# Drupal, rest server. How do i include custom fields in index view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to set up a json api in Drupal 7 using services and rest_server.

So far i can get a list of Nodes at `http://localhost/api/node.json`
and view a specific node at `http://example.com/api/node/{id}.json`

Is it possible to customise the fields that are displayed in the index view ??(`http://example.com/api/node.json`)

Specifically i want to add one or two custom fields to my custom content type which need to appear in the index json when querying the api

Comment: Why was this voted to close as off topic? It is 100% on topic and related to programming with the drupal api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, by adding the module "[Services Views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views)"

You can choose on the view all fields you need.
I just did by myself right now.
I hope that will help you or somebody :)

Jerome

Comment: Thanks, ended up rolling my own module for this particular project but wished i had know about services views